# Aural Analogue of Aesthetic

Tags: meaning, synonyms

If Aesthetic means 'visually pleasing'. What is a word that means 'aurally pleasing'.

Comment: Harmonious, music to the ears, resonant (in some contexts).

Comment: "Aesthetic" doesn't mean "visually pleasing," though.  It literally comes from a Greek root that relates to the senses/perception in general.  It's not restricted to a single type of sense, though it is perhaps most often talked about in terms of vision, because that's sense we most commonly associate with "beauty."  Scholars of music commonly talk about the "aesthetics of music/sound," and I've heard instances of it used to refer to other senses as well.

Answer (score 3):

***[Euphonic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/euphony):***

> - characterised by the quality of being pleasing to the ear, especially through a harmonious combination of words.

(ODO)

Answer (score 0):

Consider **melodious**

> Definition: pleasant to ear; of musical nature; tuneful ; sweet-sounding; musical.
>
> Example: *A melodious piece of music with round fluid movements is quite different to a piece of music with march time where count and beat go together*.